# Loading a bitmap into a CStatic control?

Tags: c++, bitmap, atl, wtl

I am trying to load a bitmap into a `CStatic` control. In my dialog I have a CStatic control which I am referring to by `_myStatic`. In my `OnInitDialog` method for the dialog I am hooking up the control to that variable and I am modifying the style to `SS_BITMAP` by `_myStatic.ModifyStyle(0,SS_BITMAP);`. The line after that I have `_myStatic.SetBitmap(::LoadBitmap(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1)));`, but the bitmap is not showing up in the CStatic. Am I missing a step in the process? The bitmap is defined in my resources.

Comment: Did you call `UpdateWindow()`? Some properties of a window are cached and changing them may require calling `UpdateWindows()` to update the cached values.

Comment: Did you verify that `LoadBitmap()` is not returning a NULL handle? Do you have the same problem with `LoadImage()`? You should be using that anyway, as `LoadBitmap()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a non-NULL first argument to the `LoadBitmap` call. Stepping the call through, make sure that effective SetBitmap argument is non-NULL as well.

```
_myStatic.SetBitmap(::LoadBitmap(
    _AtlBaseModule.GetResourceInstance(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1)));
```